# Startup composition issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef, constructor-injection

I have a `View`:

```
internal partial class StartWindow : Window
{
    public StartWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public StartWindow(IStartWindowViewModel viewModel)
        :this()
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public IStartWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }
}
```

And an appropriate `ViewModel`:

```
    [Export]
    internal class StartWindowViewModel : IStartWindowViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPD**(based on @Blachshma answer):
I can`t inject StartWindow view into my App using code:

```
public class App
{
     [ImportingConstructor]
     public App(StartWindow window)
     {
          // Do whatever you need
     }
```

because parameterless constructor need by App.g.cs:

```
internal partial class App : System.Windows.Application {

        /// <summary>
        /// Application Entry Point.
        /// </summary>
        [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        public static void Main() {
            TransparentNotification.App app = new TransparentNotification.App();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to instantiate in `app.cs` my `view` via `constructor injection`. What should I do for it?

Also, I`m looking for best practices for`MEF`/`MVVM` solutions (some sample code for this would be a great idea).

p.s. .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get an instance of the view using MEF, you first of all need to Export the view.
So add the `[Export]` attribute to your StartWindow class:

```
[Export]
partial class StartWindow : Window
{
  ...
```

Now, in your `App` class use ImportingConstrutor to get the instance:

```
public class App
{
     [ImportingConstructor]
     public App(StartWindow window)
     {
          // Do whatever you need
     }
```

Regarding good articles on MVVM, I recommend [Josh Smith's blog](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/)

Comment: I can`t inject view in App constructor. See UPD.

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi If `App` is your application's entry point, you need to build the Catalog and MEF CompositionContainer first..! [Here](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/miscellaneous/fun-with-the-microsoft-managed-extensibility-framework-part-1-3053/) is an example